# Really Quick Population Growth Question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

So I know it probably shouldn't be, but this question is throwing me through a loop.
[image]

I figured out that after about $15.629$ years (well I pretty much just took the integral from $0$ to there) the rate of increase would've been around $25,000$, but I'm confused on whether or not that's my answer. Do I just add this number to the initial population?

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me. I don't see it asking anything about the rate of increase, so I don't see anywhere to apply it.

What worries me, though, is that I don't see any analytic way to get that answer (without solving a 6th degree polynomial). Are you leaning ways to estimate integrals in class?

Comment: Yeah, we're talking about estimation. So you're saying my idea of taking the $25,000$ increase I found at $15.629$ and just add it to the initial population?

Comment: No, I'm saying just stick with 15.629. It's asking how many years it would take to go fro 25,000 to 50,000, and 15.629 is that time. BUT do not put that answer if you just used a computer/calculator to find it for you, or it will be marked incorrect. The question is asking for you to estimate, so use the methods you've been learning in class. Actually, maybe I could help if you gave the name of the method you learned.

Comment: I don't know how to mark a comment as having solved my problem, but that's what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Though, I don't feel like I answered your question. You were asked to estimate, but 15.629 is an "exact" solution. If you found the answer through estimation, then I would say post your own solution and accept it.